# How to create usergroups in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, admin, usergroups

I am building an entire system using PHP and MySQL.

I want to create usergroups.

For example
I want *ADMIN1* to be able to **ADD USER**, and **REMOVE USER**

BUT

I want *ADMIN2* to be able to **ADD USER** only

What is the standard way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple login system and use sessions to allow access to certain pages e.g.

```
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: login.php");
}
```

This example just stops the user from accessing any other pages without first logging in. The login page would change the session like so:

```
        if (!empty ($username) && !empty ($password)){
        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password ='".$password."' LIMIT 1");
        if (mysql_num_rows ($sql) > 0){
            $_SESSION['login']=1;
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            header ("Location: index.php");
        }
```

That's just a basic example but hopefully you can see what can be done using a user's table and sessions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use system used in drupal ("table_name"):

"users" [uid, name]

"users_roles" [uid, rid]

"role" [rid, name]

"permission" [pid, rid, name]

Answer (score 0):

I create roles for this, for example ADMIN1, ADMIN2 or whatever descriptive names suits best. Each user is then assigned a Role, and for pages or functions with limited access I check if the logged on user is part of the required role.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't *usergroups* in mysql. You'll need to use the grant syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Comment: I don't mean users of mysql , I mean user in my system which I am creating. you know like two admins in wordpress, one have the ability to remove topics and the other don't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Create user ‘admin1’ identified by ‘YOUR_PASSWORD’;
Revoke all on * from ‘admin1’;
Grant insert, delete, update, select on YOUR_TABLE to ‘admin1’;

Create user ‘admin2’ identified by ‘YOUR_PASSWORD’;
Revoke all on * from ‘admin2’;
Grant insert on YOUR_TABLE to ‘admin2’;
```